# two svn repositories each with an own domain name on same ubuntu server machine?

Tags: svn, dns, repository

is there a way to host two different subversion repositories each with an own domain name on the same machine (ubuntu server)?

**concrete:**
I want to have an url like "svn://domain-1.com/" with many subdirectories and repositories like "svn://domain-1.com/repo-1/", "svn://domain-1.com/repo-2/" and so on .. .. ok, thats no problem but in addition i want to have one special repository which is connectable with an other domain like "svn://domain-2.com/" without any subdirectories.

So I think about a directory with all my repositories. The domain-1 points to this directory and domain-2 points to one of the subdirectories (the special repository).

Is there a reasonably way to implement that on one ubuntu server machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible to achieve this for the HTTP protocol by using Apache/DAV and virtual hosts; see this article for details:  [Using Subversion with Apache Virtual Hosts](http://schwuk.com/articles/2004/08/28/using-subversion-with-apache-virtual-hosts/) Basically all that changes is that you use `http://hostnameX.com/repo1` rather than `svn://hostnameX.com/repo1.`

I do not believe that SVN itself supports virtual hosts, so you would have to hack some kind of reverse proxy (eg nginx) to do the same thing with svn://

Comment: Thanks a lot .. this are very helpful informations. Thanks also for the hint nginx, I didn't know this interesting server software.